# Can I make ginger bug from existing ginger beer, or from ginger beer yeast?

Tags: yeast, fermentation, ginger, beer, soda

I was having trouble getting a ginger bug started from wild cultures, so I went ahead and bought a small amount of 'Ginger Beer Yeast'.
I was hoping to get a more successful Ginger Bug started, either directly from the yeast, or potentially by backslopping (or such) from an existing ginger beer (that I plan to make with the yeast I bought as well!

Does anyone have any advice or thoughts about how to do this?

Comment: No personal experience, but my educated guess (from similar scenarios) is “should work”. Although what would be the more interesting question for me is “what caused your previous attempts to fail” - failure can teach us so much for the future.

Comment: Hmm, @Stephie I'm really not sure. The first time it fermented a bit but then stopped, and a layer of slime grew on top. It wasn't bad, just still very sweet, so my guess is it stopped fermenting.
I tried starting another bug with bottled water (since we have hard tap water here), but that just didn't really start fermenting at all. 
My only other thought is that the ginger was too clean some of the time, so maybe it was pre-treated. But it really shouldn't have been, as I fed each colony from different batches of ginger, all organic, and from different stores!
Got any other ideas?